# How to set up rack-offline in rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, offline

How to make rake-offline work in rails 3.2.11 ?

I added initializer

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure do
  #cache "images/masthead.png"

  public_path = Rails.public_path
  Dir[public_path.join("javascripts/*.js")].each do |file|
    cache file.relative_path_from(public_path)
  end

  network "/"
end
```

I added in routes

```
match "/application.manifest" => Rails::Offline

  Rack::Offline.configure do
    cache "assets/application.js"
    cache "assets/application.css"   
    network "/"
  end
```

and added manifest in html tag.

It throws error

```
/initializers/offline.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `join' for "/Sites/Ruby/project/public":String (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3.2.11, `Rails.public_path` returns a `String`, not a `Pathname` object. (It looks like Rails master has it returning a `Pathname` object which is why rack-offline's documentation might say to use it that way).

Try this instead:

```
  public_path = Pathname.new(Rails.public_path)
```

See https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline/issues/7

Comment: It works. Thx Dylan. Any idea why /application.manifest does not list js and css files by default?

Comment: In rails 4 `Rails.public_path` once again returns a `Pathname` object so this solution will no longer be be relevant (you know, if you're working in rails 4).